# make check fails in postgresql regression tests in ubuntu in virtualbox

Tags: postgresql, virtualbox

I am running regression tests in Postgresql in Ubuntu in VirtualBox. The other commands; `./configure` and `make install` works fine but when I test to see if the postgresql will work fine as expected I get this error: `pg_regres:initdb failed`as shown below:

```
============== creating temporary instance            ==============
============== initializing database system           ==============

pg_regress: initdb failed
Examine /home/mucheru/postgres/src/test/regress/log/initdb.log for the reason.
Command was: "initdb" -D "/home/mucheru/postgres/src/test/regress/./tmp_check/data" --no-clean --no-sync > "/home/mucheru/postgres/src/test/regress/log/initdb.log" 2>&1
make[1]: *** [GNUmakefile:126: check] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mucheru/postgres/src/test/regress'
make: *** [GNUmakefile:69: check] Error 2
root@ubuntuos:/home/mucheru/postgres#
```

I have examined the initdb.log which say it cannot be run in root.The log:

```
Running in no-clean mode.  Mistakes will not be cleaned up.
initdb: error: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.
```

I was expecting to see the `make test` successful with no errors. I have tried to rebuild again unsuccessfully and checking the system requirements.

Comment: Without any more details, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: Please paste the complete exact error message from the log file, as well as the command line used.

Comment: I have added the log and the error message.

Comment: `initdb: error: cannot be run as root` - are you 100% certain that you *are not* running as root and can you show how you determined that?

Comment: Sorry. First I run as unprivileged and failed due to permission issue, then as root . The log shown is after running as a root. So I am thinking what might be the problem because the log does not give more info.

Comment: You need to run as a nonprivileged user, and in a directory which that user has permissions to.  You can't really expect the log files to tell you about the next error, the one you haven't committed yet.

Comment: What might be the issue @jjanes if there is permission issues after running as nonprivileged user?

Comment: Presumably it finds itself, after the `su`, in someone else's directory, one it doesn't have access to anymore.  The rest of the error message if there were more might clarify that.

Comment: Just the error messages in the terminal as I put them above. Or possibly, VM needs specific configuration to run Postgres smoothly.